# Android how to properly finish an activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I am making an android game using the SurfaceView/Thread model seen in many of the examples. I am trying to split the components into multiple activities. Right now I have a menu activity and a game activity. For some reason when I attempt to finish the game activity to return to the menu activity my app will become unresponsive. It seems to work fine on the emulator but on my device (Samsung Mesmerize) it will become unresponsive. I have a feeling this is because a thread is still busy in the game activity but I have no idea how to kill the thread. I tried breaking the game loop as well and that did not seem to help.

My SurfaceView has an inner thread class, here is the implementation of run()

```
public void run()
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        Canvas c = null;
        while(_isRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized(_surfaceHolder)
                {
                    if(_engine != null)
                    {
                        _engine.gameLogic();
                        if(c != null)
                            _engine.draw(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(c != null)
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are sure it is caused by thread, consider using a [threadpool](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) manage/control all your threads life cycle, to kill them all, simply call ExecutorService.shutdownNow();

Comment: Im not really sure. Im thinking it could be a thread that isnt finishing. Sometimes the activity successfully exits to the base activity and sometimes the app becomes totally unresponsive. It seems to work correctly on the emulator.

Comment: Then improve your question with code snippet and exception stack trace may help other people find your problem.

Comment: No exception is ever thrown. The app just becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem after an hour or two of debugging. I had to keep track of whether the surface was alive before calling lockCanvas(). I used this same loop in both activities and calling lockCanvas() after the surface from the game activity was destroyed was causing problems.